# Save subprocess.Popen() to utf-8 encoded file

Tags: python, bash, utf-8

I'm currently trying to output subprocess to a file, but I need the output file to be in utf-8.  It currently outputs a ASCII file.

This is my code:

```
with open('coolfile'), 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as z:
    make_zone_record = subprocess.Popen(
            ['zonefile', '-g', 'filetoconvert.json'], stdout=z)
```

I'm using python 3.6.5.  I'm not sure if it's the subprocess program I am using [zonefile](https://github.com/elgs/dns-zonefile) that is the issue or the subprocess module as to why it doesn't come out in utf-8.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. If the output is in ASCII, it is automatically also UTF-8.